# print multidimensional array in json response

Tags: php, json

How can print multidimensional array of single array.

```
$data = array(
                'ride_categry'=>$ridecategory,
                'pool_ride_type'=> $pollride,
                'ride_looking_for'=> $ridefor,
                'seating_capacity'=>$seatingcapcity,
                'ride_from'=> $rideform,
                'ride_to'=> $rideto,
                'daily_route'=> $daily,
                //'ride_now'=>  $ridenow,
                'ride_date'=> $ridedate,
               'ride_time'=> $ridetime,
        );
```

print this in multidimensional array like

Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [two] => Array
                (
                    [three] => Array
                        (
                            [four] => 
                        )
                )
        )
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP arrays are not multi-dimensional, they are nested. The example you gave does not illustrate a nested array.

If you want to exchange compound data structures between PHP and Javascript then use the builtin JSON routines:

```
<?php
$data=array(...);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: symcbean@ok my response is good need only create in multidimanisoanl

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all the nested data from $data use print_r function:

```
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Damian Dziaduch@you there?